# xcode cannot compile NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parsing

xcode will not compile a FRESH project with only libxml2 and its requirements installed. it returns this error every time.

http://puu.sh/bYc7D/b37d7c6e99.png

I do not know how to resolve this, has anyone had this before?

Comment: Xcode doesn't think that's an Objective-C header file, or there's something amiss with the precompiled headers.  You shouldn't need to import the Foundation classes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like `Foundation` isn't imported.  Do you have anything in your prefix header file?

Regardless, try importing it into your header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Or alternatively if you use modules:

```
@import Foundation;
```

Comment: Thank you, I just assumed the file would have automatically contained that. My mistake. I do not know much about objectiveC so i've been struggling to port my app over to iOS

Answer (score 1):

Most of the standard project templates include a prefix header called `project_name-Prefix.pch` (and a reference to it in build settings, search for 'prefix').

Since most classes use the Foundation library, including Foundation.h in that header is a good idea.  Also make sure that Foundation.framework is included under "Build Phases" -> "Link Binary With Libraries".

If your project isn't setup that way, it might be useful to create a new project using the most basic template (like Single View), observe how its setup and do the same things to your project.

Answer (score -1):

Import Fondation? I don't see it at the top of the file.